# Quarkus and Keycloak/OIDC - NullPointerException

Tags: java, jwt, openid-connect, keycloak, quarkus

I'm working on a suite of microservices using the Quarkus 1.0.1 framework.  I'd like to secure these using Keycloak 8.0.1 as my identity provider.  I've got Keycloak up and running in a Docker container and have configured a realm and corresponding client for my microservices.  Now I'm to the point where I want to secure them and I'm running into a problem.

My REST service has no `@RolesAllowed` annotation or any authorization requirements configured for it.  That should mean that I am able to hit the service even when I'm not authenticated.  However, when I attempt this I see this exception:

```
20:55:29 ERROR [io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.QuarkusErrorHandler] HTTP Request to /api/v1/mymethod failed, error id: 666dd651-6a8b-4004-9c11-3c5bee54503f-5: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.quarkus.keycloak.pep.KeycloakPolicyEnforcerAuthorizer.apply(KeycloakPolicyEnforcerAuthorizer.java:44)
    at io.quarkus.keycloak.pep.KeycloakPolicyEnforcerAuthorizer.apply(KeycloakPolicyEnforcerAuthorizer.java:28)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.security.HttpAuthorizer$1$1.run(HttpAuthorizer.java:65)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.CleanableExecutor$CleaningRunnable.run(CleanableExecutor.java:224)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2011)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1535)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1426)
    at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
    at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:479)
```

My `application.properties` file looks like this:

```
quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url=http://localhost:8880/auth/realms/myrealm
quarkus.oidc.client-id=myreal-default
quarkus.oidc.credentials.secret=<SECRET UUID>
quarkus.oidc.authentication.scopes=oidc
quarkus.oidc.application-type=service
```

...and I am testing using curl like this:

```
curl -vki -H  http://localhost:8080/api/v1/mymethod
```

I thought this might be due to the fact that I have not authenticated, so I obtained a Keycloak JWT and added it as an Authorization header.  This still didn't work, failing with the same exception.  I am not doing anything funky with Keycloak.  My configuration is pretty plain vanilla at this point, so I can't imagine that the issue lies in my code itself.  Am I missing something in my configuration?  Or is this a bug within Keycloak?

Comment: have you tried setting quarkus.keycloak.policy-enforcer.enable=true in your property file? I took it from this guide: https://quarkus.io/guides/security-keycloak-authorization this solved my exception.

Comment: I did. That didn't seem to make a difference, though.

Answer (score 2):

That one is simple: a NullPointerException is always a bug. We have fixed some issues related to Keycloak 8 but that one doesn't seem related.

Please open an issue on our bugtracker (https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues), preferably with a sample app reproducing the issue.

We have a release planned on Tuesday morning so if you can create this as early as possible, that would help.

Comment: I experienced almost the same error, but with KC 6. Can you tell me whether you test your bug fixes only with the newest KC or with older versions, too? If yes how low (version number) do you go?

Comment: It was working with Keycloak 7 and we upgraded our tests to 8. I'm pretty sure we never tested things with Keycloak 6.

Comment: thank you for the info. actually I mislead myself by having the same stacktrace as op has and didn't think any further. Today I had a look at the quarkus keycloak guide and realized I didn't set quarkus.keycloak.policy-enforcer.enable=true Now it works. Yay :D